# With the .NET "WinForms" SplitContainer control, how can I hide a panel dynamically?

Tags: .net, winforms, splitcontainer

Calling MyPanel.Panel1.Hide(); or MyPanel.Panel2.Hide(); simply hides the controls *inside* the panel... but I want to have the *other* side of the panel fill up the whole space.

So, if I hide Panel1, I want Panel2 to take up the whole space, and I want the splitter to disappear. Is that possible, if so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `MyPanel.Panel1Collapsed = true;` to collapse Panel1 (likewise for panel2).

Answer (score 2):

To hide one of the panels you can call

```
MyPanel.Panel1Collapsed = true; // or Panel2Collapsed
```

If Panel2 was collapsed, it will toggle its state to be shown after this call.

[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.panel1collapsed(v=VS.80).aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the additional information about the other panel showing up when setting the first one.